# Linking to specific jQuery accordian UI

Tags: jquery, accordion

I'm using the jQuery accordion UI - http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/
...and would like to link to a specific accordion in the footer, so that the link takes you to the specific page AND opens up the specific accordion.

In the plugin, the headers are links, so i added: name="contact" and then i've linked to /*pagename*#contact but it won't open up the accordian so it renders it pointless.

What can I do? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that you are supposed to make the header `<a href="#contact">` for the content  of the accordion item you are linking to.

Also you must setup accordion like this: `.accordion({ navigation:true })`

Edit: http://jsfiddle.net/M5JQn/

Comment: thanks joe. i've done this but now when i go to /*pagename*/#contact it just takes me to the page with all 3 accordions closed, and does not open the contact one automatically.

Comment: i've attached a demo, take a look at the structure and code there

Answer (score 0):

from: http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#method-activate

.accordion( "activate" , index )

Activate a content part of the Accordion programmatically. The index can be a zero-indexed number to match the position of the header to close or a Selector matching an element.

Pass false to close all (only possible with collapsible:true).

So when the link in the footer is clicked on:
    onclick" open the page; $('accname').accordion('activate',2)"

UPDATE:
since the activate is like a click each time it won't always open it so you have to get it's state first, use:
    if($('#accordion').accordion('option', 'active')!=1) {$('#accordionp').accordion('option', 'active', 1);}
That will ensure it's open each time you go to it.

Answer (score 0):

Forget what i said below. It's a general approach other than jquery ui.
There is a better way as "Joe Flateau" mentioned and [this](http://www.michaeljacobdavis.com/tutorials/statesavingaccordion/statesavingaccordion.html#2) is a good example for it.

---

There's something like this in documentation. 
Is it what you need?
    $( ".selector" ).accordion({ active: 2 });

You can define an array like:

```
var pages=new Array(); 
pages['main']=1;
pages['contact']=2;
pages['help']=3;
//and whatsoever
```

Then you can open that page with the information from the url hash:

```
var hash = window.location.hash
$( ".selector" ).accordion({ active: pages[hash] });
```